# Is it possible to create a user defined aggregate function for DB2 without the privilege to upload compiled files..?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Before I embark on a quest which ultimately proves hopeless, I'd like to ask those with greater experience...

Is it possible to create a user defined aggregate function for DB2 without privileges to upload compiled files..? This is for DB2 for AS400 on iSeries v7r3m0.

My first thought was to create the UDAF as a normal SQL function via my SQL client DBeaver 5.2.5. I've created regular UDFs this way before, however I'm not sure if an aggregate function can be written this way. I have yet to find any examples online, and this [one IBM document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCRJT_5.0.4/com.ibm.swg.im.bigsql.commsql.doc/doc/r0070019.html) isn't for my version.

If this cannot be done in SQL, then the next option is JAVA. My skills there are basic yet sufficient to explore the possibility, but it'd be my first time doing so on DB2. What may be the major roadblock there is in my understanding that JAVA functions for DB2 require uploading compiled files to the server, but I do not have privileges to do this. Unless I'm incorrect on this point..?

My next thought was whether JAVA functions can be *written and compiled on the server..?* For instance, can I write JAVA code in a script window of my SQL client, so when I run the script, the JAVA is *compiled by the server*, and then *stored on the server..?* Or perhaps is there's a JAVA development client like IBM Data Studio which connects to the server just the same..?

Or...something..? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I'll explain the UDAF I wish to create. It would be similar to any built-in UDAF like SUM(), but it would be character-based, and its name would be `GetCommonWords`. The input would be a table column of type `CHAR(n)`. The output would also be `CHAR(n)`, with a string of words that are common to the beginning of all records.

Consider the following phrases for the column `"FOOD"`:

- peanut butter
- peanut butter and jelly
- peanut butter cup
- peanut butter jelly time

The usage would be `GetCommonWords(Food)`, and the result would be the words common to all: `peanut butter`.

Comment: One way to work around the limitation that @PaulVernon correctly points out would be to use the relatively new aggregate function `ARRAY_AGG`.  This would not work for an RPG External Scalar solution, but it would work in Java because of support for SQL arrays and would probably work in pure SQL too. You can group using `ARRAY_AGG`, take that array, and pass it as a parameter to your UDF. You can then return a scalar result. If you wanted an RPG solution, you could probably do something similar with `LISTAGG`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Db2 for i does not have a `CREATE FUNCTION (aggregate)` statement even in the current 7.4 release.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcreatef.htm

You should know that Db2 for i, Db2 for z and Db2 (for LUW) are essentially separate products, and although there is certain amount of common syntax and features, you do need to look at manual pages (and web articles etc) for your particular platform (and ideally version level)

Comment: Thank you. That answers a number of questions that I've had. I do use the documentation a lot, in fact the 7.4 home page is a link on my toolbar, and I was in there for a couple of hours yesterday trying to figure this out.

Comment: For the record Db2 (for LUW) and Db2 Warehouse does have `CREATE FUNCTION (aggregate) ` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070019.html

Comment: Well...we are on a cloud of sorts. It's a hosted DB2 system. Our old private system was i7(?), but I recall someone saying "Power9" when we upgraded to the "cloud". It's our inventory, order, & bookkeeping system, and shared with all of their customers, so I have rights to do some things but not others. But...that link you shared above...? The very last code example is for an aggregate function with `LANGUAGE SQL`..!! =-D That's the first one I've been able to find. I'm going to try it just to see what  happens. Maybe I'll get lucky and it'll work.

Comment: If you are using Db2 for i, then you will have no luck.  There would be ways to achieve what you want in SQL.  E.g. a Stored Procedure could process a cursor, or you could use recursive SQL to the same ends https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcomtexp.htm  or you could use a table function to split your strings out into indexed rows, then some "normal" aggregation should beable to get you the result (if rather in-efficiently)   but none would be as elegant as an aggregate UDF that you could use in any query.

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to cook up something as a stored function. Staring at it pondering the ways of the code now, with cte's, if's, loops, and regex etc.

Comment: Also, studying the different SQL functions in that linked article is helping with the ideas.